# Dplyr keeps automatically adding one of my columns

Tags: r, dplyr

So, I have a large data.frame with multiple columns of which "trial.number" and "indexer" are 2.

It annoys me that dplyr constantly, no matter what, adds indexer column.
A simple example:

```
saccade.df %>%
  distinct(trial.number, .keep_all = F)
```

I would expect to see the the unique trial.numbers and only the trial.number column. However, the output looks like this:

[image]

How do I stop dplyr from doing this? And why isn't it showing the unique trial.numbers but only the unique indexer (for which I didnt even ask).

```
example.df <- data.frame(trial.number = rep(1:10, each = 10), time = 
seq(1:100), indexer = rep(21:30, each = 10))

example.df %>%
 distinct(trial.number, .keep_all = F)
```

This goes give the right output. However, I somehow grouped my own variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: was `indexer` a grouping variable?

Comment: if i class saccade.df , i get grouped_df, tbl_df, tbl, data.frame. @avid_useR

Comment: `dplyr` automatically adds the grouping variable back. So you need to `ungroup()` before you can remove it

Comment: Thanks. This was all that frustrated me. @avid_useR

Comment: No, didn't get any message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `ungroup` :

```
df <- data.frame(trial.number=1:2,indexer=3:4)

df %>% distinct(trial.number)
#  trial.number
#1            1
#2            2

df %>% group_by(trial.number,indexer) %>% distinct(trial.number)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
## Groups:   trial.number, indexer [2]
#  trial.number indexer
#         <int>   <int>
#1            1       3
#2            2       4

df %>% group_by(trial.number,indexer) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(trial.number)
## A tibble: 2 x 1
#  trial.number
#         <int>
#1            1
#2            2
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about that.

Comment: `group_by` adds an attribute to the data frame for each column and only `summarize` (or so) remove them (one by one), so when you are done with grouping it is safer to systematcally ungroup.